# How can i get dnsmasq version 2.63 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, dnsmasq

I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS. with dnsmasq 2.59

I am running a commands which shows error of requirement unsatisfied.
The dnsmasq version needs to be 2.63 or more than that.

How can i get it.

I tried apt-get install dnsamsq. But it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by building dnsmasq 2.63 from source.

Documentation: http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html

Downloads: http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/

1. Get the tarball:

   `wget http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/dnsmasq-2.63.tar.gz`
2. Extract it:

   `tar -xvf dnsmasq-2.63.tar.gz`
3. Build and install the code:

   `cd dnsmasq-2.63/
   sudo make install`
4. Restart the dnsmasq service:

   `sudo service dnsmasq stop
    sudo service dnsmasq start`
5. Check the version:

   `dnsmasq --version
    Dnsmasq version 2.63rc6  Copyright (c) 2000-2012 Simon Kelley`